# Blank Page after Centered Landscape Table

Tags: tables, landscape

I have a table that is centered on a page (which works) and looks visually correct - however, a blank page is added after the table.

Reproducible Example:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lscape} % for rotating table
\usepackage{float} % for [p] at table
\usepackage{graphicx} % for making table smaller
\usepackage{textcomp} % for arrows

\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\resizebox{1.55\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{C}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{MM}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{MA}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{ABCD}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{F}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Strategy} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{NB}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{KNN}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{SVM}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{C4.5}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{NB}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{KNN}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{SVM}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{C4.5}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{NB}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{KNN}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{SVM}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{C4.5}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{NB}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{KNN}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{SVM}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{C4.5}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{NB}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{KNN}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{SVM}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{C4.5}} \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_CBOW\_50 &  
  00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_CBOW\_50 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_CBOW\_100 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  00.00 &
  \textbf{0.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_CBOW\_100 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_CBOW\_200 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  0.00&
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{0.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_CBOW\_200 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
00.00 &
0.00&
00.00 &
00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_SG\_50 &
00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_SG\_50 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{\underline{00.00}} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 0.00& \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{\underline{00.00}} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 \\ \hline \hline 
Light\_500\_4\_SG\_100 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  00.00 &
  00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_SG\_100 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  00.00 &
  \textbf{\underline{00.00}} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_SG\_200 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  \textbf{\underline{00.00}} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{0.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00&
  00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_SG\_200 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  0.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{00.00} &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  00.00 &
  \textbf{\underline{00.00}} &
  00.00 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
} % resize
\caption{Caption.}%
\label{tab:classification_results_new}
\end{table}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{1.55\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{C}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{MM}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{MA}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{ABCD}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{F}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Strategy} &
  \textbf{LR} &
  \textbf{KNN} &
  \textbf{M5} &
  \textbf{LR} &
  \textbf{KNN} &
  \textbf{M5} &
  \textbf{LR} &
  \textbf{KNN} &
  \textbf{M5} &
  \textbf{LR} &
  \textbf{KNN} &
  \textbf{M5} &
  \textbf{LR} &
  \textbf{KNN} &
  \textbf{M5} \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_CBOW\_50   & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 \\
Classic\_500\_4\_CBOW\_50 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_CBOW\_100   & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00  & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_CBOW\_100 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00  \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_CBOW\_200   & 00.00    & \textbf{00.00} & 0.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 0.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00  & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_CBOW\_200 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00  \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_SG\_50     & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 0.00& 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \underline{\textbf{00.00}} & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_SG\_50 & 00.00 & \textbf{\underline{00.00}} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{\underline{00.00}} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_SG\_100     & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \underline{\textbf{00.00}}  & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 100.00 & 00.00 & 0.00 & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_SG\_100   & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \underline{\textbf{00.00}} & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00}  & 00.00 & 00.00  & 00.00 & 0.00 & 00.00 \\ \hline \hline
Light\_500\_4\_SG\_200     & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 100.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ %\hline
Classic\_500\_4\_SG\_200   & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 0.00 & \textbf{00.00} & 0.00 & 100.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}% % added for resize box
\caption{Caption.}%
\label{tab:regression_results}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: Also, don't use `resizebox` on a table. This will lead toinconsistent font sizes throughout your document.

Comment: Yes, different font sizes are not elegant -- but often seen in page-limited scientific articles...

Comment: In my opintion there is nothing wrong with decreasing the font size per se. You could for example do so using commands like `\small` or `\footnotesize`. If you use these commands throughout your document, the font sizes of all smaller texts will be the same. If you use `resizebox`  on different tables, you will end up with a variety of smaller font sizes instead.

Comment: Great remark! I could change both tables to `\footnotesize` and they still fit on the page.